# Problem in Getting values from an array in PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework

iam using the Zend framework and  assign the array from the controller to 
view. The array is coming from execution of stored procedure result

```
$results = callProcedure('testprocedure', $in)//$in is an array of input values 
$view->results =$results['record'];
```

In The `$results['record']` array iam having two values such as `'NO'` and `'name'` and  i
   want to assign this values also the view.However this values will be available in the `$results['record'];` array.
   But in the  view i need have the values separately i dont repeat them in the loop .
   if i dont do for each  iam not getting the values

How do i assign these values from  the controller

```
$view->no=???
$view->NAME=???
```

How do i access `$results['record']`  array in the view

```
$this->results['NO']//  it is saying undefined index 'NO'
$this->results['NAME']// it is saying undefined index 'NAME'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the vies from the controller you must use `$this->view->`. Then from the view its `$this->` because when in the view $this is the view object itself.

so try:

```
$results = callProcedure('testprocedure', $in)//$in is an array of input values 
$this->view->results = $results['record'];
```

From the controller it looks like this echoing them:

```
echo 'no: ' .$this->view->results['no']. '<BR />';
echo 'name: ' .$this->view->results['name'];
```

So do to it from the view just:

```
<?php
    echo 'no: ' . $this->results['no'] . '<BR />';
    echo 'name: ' . $this->results['name'];
?>
```

Comment: @lznogood:$this->view->var = ???????(How should i assign the NO and Name from the array Should i say ($results['record'][NO])

Comment: Edited my answer. Was more explaining the principles then coding you the answer.

Comment: @Someone I reEdited my answer with more details. Hope it is clear to you now and you can accept my answer.